# Alternative for underPageBackgroundColor

Tags: ios7, deprecated

Xcode says that `underPageBackgroundColor` is deprecated in iOS 7. What is the alternative for iOS 7? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no alternative, because that's the pre iOS 7 style background color. You have to use the "layered" approach now with blurry backgrounds, or just plain white.